# Semisimple representation theory of finite groups in characteristic p.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, positive-characteristic

For $G$ a finite group, and algebraically closed field $k$ of finite characteristic coprime to $|G|$, we have that $k[G]$ is a semisimple algebra. This gives complete reducibility, and I vaguely recall the degrees of the irreps are the same as the irreps in characteristic 0.

How "good" is the bijection of the irreducible representations over $k$ and those over $\mathbb{C}$?

Is this bijection functorial with respect to the induction/restriction functors, (or at least on the level of isoclasses)?

Does the bijection extend to an isomorphism of the groethendieck rings of representations $R_k[G]$ and $R_\mathbb{C}[G]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might as well assume that $k=\Bbb F_{p^k}$, a finite field, as all characteristic $p$ representations will be realisable over such a field. By the formalism of Brauer characters, such representations can be lifted to reps defined
over the ring $R_p$, the ring of integers of the maximal unramified extension
$\Bbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ of $\Bbb Q_p$. 
(You can realise $R_p$ as a ring of Witt vectors over $k$.)
Likewise given a representation of $G$
on a vector space over $\Bbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$, there's a $R_p$-lattice $\Lambda$ 
invariant under $G$, and reducing modulo $p$ gives a representation over $k$.
All of this is functorial, and for details see Serre's book on representation theory.

To bring in $\Bbb C$ one needs an embedding $i:\Bbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}\to\Bbb C$.
Once one has this one has a functorial correspondence between reps over
$i:\Bbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ and over $\Bbb C$. But this embedding is **not unique**,
and there is no canonical embedding. So the answer to your question is "yes, up to the choice of the embedding $i$."

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, we can realise these irreps over $\mathbb{C}$ by extending scalars from $\mathbb{Q}_p^{ur}$ along our embedding $i$, thus giving an isomorphism of groethendieck rings. Do you know if this morphism depends on the embedding $i$?

Comment: @user277182 In general it will depend on the embedding. The point of course is that $\Bbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ has a lot more (continuous) automorphisms than $\Bbb C$.